# Riddle about mysterious family

Tags: riddle, rhyme

```
When you get to know me
I'll be long time gone.

If you ever saw me
I was someone else back then.

I have two younger siblings
and the middle one is your best peer.

The youngest one you haven't met.
And when you meet,
he'll disappear.
```

The question is, who are the mysterious brothers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that:

> It is the past, the present and the future.

I reached this by guessing what would reasonably fit in the given text, and noting that:

> All the narrative are about the **time** of when something happens.

```
When you get to know me
I'll be long time gone.
```

> When you know the past (the one who refers himself/herself as "me"), it is something that do not exists anymore.

```
If you ever saw me
I was someone else back then.
```

> When you saw the past, it was not the past, it was the present.

```
I have two younger siblings
and the middle one is your best peer.
```

> The past has two younger siblings, the present and the future. The present is your best peer.

```
The youngest one you haven't met.
And when you meet,
he'll disappear.
```

> When you meet the future, he will be the present instead, and immediately become the past.

Answer (score 9):

They are:

> YESTERDAY, TODAY AND TOMORROW

And you are:

> YESTERDAY

**Explaination**

When you get to know me
I'll be long time gone.

> When a day is "yesterday" it is forever "gone".

If you ever saw me
I was someone else back then.

> "Yesterday" (as a day) changed every day. i.e. for every day there is a different "yesterday".

I have two younger siblings

> "younger" means they first occur later in time (fits with "today" and "tomorrow").

and the middle one is your best peer.

> "today" is the one we are always "with".

The youngest one you haven't met.
And when you meet,
he'll disappear.

> "tomorrow" is the "youngest". When we encounter "tomorrow" (i.e. arrive there in time), it has become "today".

Comment: Wow, two correct answers within two minutes of the question being posted! Impressive performance from both of you.